# how do you select all checkboxes when user clicks a button

Tags: jquery

i have a form with a "Select All" button and a bunch of checkboxes.  i want to have it select all checkboxes when the user clicks the "Select All" button.

is there elegant way in jquery to do this?

EDIT #2: i have isolated the problem down to this code; style="display: none;".  if i remove this code it works fine.  any ideas?

EDIT: The answers below work in my test form but the button in this case is inside of a form that is inside of a div that only shows up as part of a simpledialog.show(). in this case, for some reason when i click on the button i dont see anything happen:

javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#sdHc3').simpleDialog({
        showCloseLabel: false,
        open: function() {
            $('#checkboxStatus').html('');
        },
        close: function() {
            var c = [];
            $('#checkboxForm :checkbox:checked').each(function() {
                c.push($(this).val());
            });
            $('#checkboxStatus').html('&nbsp;&nbsp;Checked <b>' + c.join(', ') + '</b>.').show();
        }
    });

});
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$('#selectAll').click(function() {
        var select_all = (this.value === 'Select All');
        $(':checkbox').attr('checked', select_all);
        this.value = (select_all) ? 'Deselect All' : 'Select All';
    });
});
```

body:

```
<div style="display: none;" class="scrollableDiv" id="simpleDialog3">
    <h3>DEMO3</h3>
    <form id="checkboxForm">
    <input type="button" id="selectAll" value="TT" />
    <input type="checkbox" class="chckbx" value="1" /><br />
    <input type="checkbox" class="chckbx" value="1" /><br />
    </form>
    <p>
        <a href="#" class="close">Close</a></p>
</div>
```

any idea why it wouldn't work in this case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$(function(){
    $('#myButton').click(function(){
        var select_all = (this.value === 'Select All');
        $('input:checkbox').attr('checked', select_all);
        this.value = (select_all) ? 'Deselect All' : 'Select All';        
    });
});
```

Try placing this code before your dialog instantiation.

It seems like you may want to switch to [jQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/).

Comment: I would put the $('input[type=checkbox']) selector in the this.form context.  I would also use a flag instead of this.value for checking if all should be checked or not.  (Also, if one checkbox is unchecked, the text isn't changed, etc.)

Comment: Also also, I would use the :checkbox selector instead of checking the type, as it's cleaner-looking, as in GApple's answer.

Comment: this works fine on my test form, but in my new case, th3e button is inside a div that is by default hidden and then shows up inside of dialog.  for some reason in this case it doesn't work

Comment: Can you give some more context in your example?

Comment: The documentation also recommends 'input:checkbox' over just ':checkbox', as using just the pseudo-selector maps to the slower value '*:checkbox'

Comment: have isolated the problem down to this code; style="display: none;". if i remove this code it works fine. any ideas?

Comment: @oo, The dialog doesn't show.  You seem to be missing that code.

Comment: Update for posterity: as of jQuery 1.6, checkboxes and radio buttons should be marked by calling `.prop('checked',true)` instead of `.attr('checked', [anything])`.

Answer (score 2):

Having your button call this when clicked will select all checkboxes on the page:

```
jQuery("input:checkbox").attr('checked','checked');
```

You can change the selector ("input:checkbox") to provide better context (and possibly speed up it's execution as well)

- [Attr()](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/attr#keyvalue)
- [:checkbox](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/checkbox)

Comment: Update for posterity: as of jQuery 1.6, checkboxes and radio buttons should be marked by calling `.prop('checked',true)` instead of `.attr('checked', 'checked')`.

Answer (score 1):

So if your select-all button has an id of select-all you say:

```
$('#select-all').click(function(){
   $('input:checkbox').attr('checked', 'checked');   
);
```

Answer (score 0):

just give all the checkboxes a class, and attach this jQuery to the button:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
  $('#myButton').click( function() {
    $('.checkbox').attr('checked','checked');
  });
}
```

Assuming your button has the id="myButton" and your checkboxes have the class="checkbox".

Comment: instead of ".checkbox" (assign "checkbox" as a class on all inputs that should be selected) you can use "input[type=checkbox]"

Comment: `input:checkbox` is neater, but still could lead to unwanted checkboxes being ticked, depending on the other elements on the page.

Answer (score 0):

In the cases where I've wanted the same functionality, it usually is a table of rows with checkboxes down the side. In that case, you could include this code snippet and then any time there is a checkbox in a header cell, all the associated checkboxes in the column below it will be switched on/off depending on its value.

Assuming HTML like this:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><input type="checkbox" /></th>
            <th>...</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="row[0]" /></td>
            <td>...</td>
        </tr>
        ...
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here's the jQuery:

```
$('th input:checkbox').click(function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        colNum = $this.closest('th').prevAll('th').length,
        checked = $this.attr('checked')
    ;
    $this
        .closest('table')
        .find('tbody > tr')
        .each(function() {
            $(this)
                .children("td")
                .eq(colNum)
                .find("input:checkbox")
                .attr('checked', checked)
            ;
        })
    ;
});
```

It doesn't require any extra ids or classes or anything and can work for multiple columns of checkboxes, which is nice. Here's a demo page: http://jsbin.com/eqeno

Comment: if this inside a div your code doesn't seem to work.  i have put an example here:  http://jsbin.com/oyuha

Comment: That will be something to do with the other plugin you're using - using a `live()` event instead of `click()` would probably solve that.

Comment: what is the live() event.  i tried it and it didn't seem to do anything

Comment: http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live it will apply your event handlers to elements which are added to the DOM later